# Understanding Object URLS for client-side files and how to free the memory

Tags: javascript, image, html, fileapi

I am using `createObjectURL` to get a reference URL  to a local image file.  When I am done with the file/image, I call `revokeObjectURL` to free that memory.  Everything works fine for me but I just want to be sure that I am releasing all the memory I can.

My concern arose after I inspected the `chrome://blob-internals` page.  Upon calling `createObjectURL` and using the image, I noticed two entries were created.  One with url 
`blob:blobinternal:///d17c4eef-28e7-42bd-bafa-78d5cb86e761`

and the other

`blob:http://localhost/dbfe7b09-81b1-48a4-87cd-d579b96adaf8`

Both referred to the same local file path though.  Upon calling `revokeObjectURL` only the second entry was removed from `chrome://blob-internals`.  Why does this occur, how do I get rid of the other entry and what is the difference between the two types?

Also, I have seen examples of people revoking the URL before even using the image.  What effect does this have?

Some insight into the topic would be much appreciated! :)

**EDIT**:
I've created an example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag92S/5/).  So first open [blobinternals](http://chrome://blob-internals/) and remove any existing blobs.  Then run the jsfiddle example, and choose an image file on your machine.  Then refresh blobinternals to see what it added.  Then click "revoke URL" in my example.  Finally refresh blobinternals to see what blobs remain.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? I'm not seeing this on Chrome 15 Dev channel (only one blobURL is created), but remember seeing this before. Do you have a small test page that can repo the two URLs being produced? It's been my experience that `chrome://blob-internals` sometimes takes a few seconds to reflect the `revokeObjectURL` call.

Comment: I've edited my post to include a jsfiddle example. I'm running chrome 14beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other reference (the one beginning with `blob:blobinternal`) seems to be held by the `input type="file"` element. I modified your function to reset the value of the input, and when I click the revoke URL button, all the references are cleared:

```
killBut.onclick = function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(ourURL);
    fileBut.value = '';
};
```

Tested in Chrome Canary.

Comment: This seems to work for me too.  Good thinking and thanks! One question: Is the file input element not read-only in IE? If so, how would one clear it?

Comment: Clear it by putting it in a `form` element and calling `reset()` on that. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ag92S/9/

Comment: In chrome canary the representation of `chrome:\\blob-internals` is much better. You can see the uniquely generated blob's and how often they are referenced. For eg. you have a link with href reference and a object with reference to the same blob => the refcount of that blob is 2.