# URL.createObjectURL causes memory leak

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display images with `URL.createObjectURL`. However, it takes so much memory, about 10 times of image size.
Here is my code:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
image.className = 'images';
image.onload = function(){
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
};
$('.images').appendTo('body');
```

Is this a browser bug? Or something's wrong with my code?

Comment: May the size difference be caused by the Encoding of the resulting data-Url?

Comment: @Grumbler85 I don't get your point. My variable `blob` is a local image received via input file element.

Comment: @user3925697 how you realized that 10 times difference? may i know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually you call [URL.revokeObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.revokeObjectURL) when you release an existing object URL which was previously created by calling [window.URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) for optimal performance and memory usage, if there are safe times when you can explicitly unload them.

But you can't save memory through creating object, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23810853/2791480), and this [helper link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781216.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your links. BTW, do you mean it's a browser bug?