# Is URL.createObjectURL() a thin wrapper around a Blob, or does it hold its own copy of the buffer?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, createobjecturl

The [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static) function allows you to create a temporary URL from a Blob. I am aware that this function [can leak memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25698581/2854284) (until the page is unloaded), so that it is often important to call the corresponding `revokeObjectURL()` function to free the memory, especially if you're calling it in a loop. My question is not about such leaks, but instead about the memory overheads to `createObjectURL()` and the implications for *when* to call `revokeObjectURL()`.

Most image Blobs would hold compressed data, which the browser of course needs to decompress in order to show the image. Does `createObjectURL()` create a thin wrapper around the Blob? Or does it decompress the image and then stores the full bitmap data until `revokeObjectURL()` is called? <s>Or perhaps it makes its own immutable copy of the data so that changes to the Blob's data don't affect it?</s> (Blobs are immutable so there'd be no reason to make a copy.)

In my case I'll still be holding the Blob in memory, and so if `createObjectURL()` only makes a thin wrapper then I could keep the object URL in case I need to use it more than once. But if the overhead is high because it owns a large block of memory then I'd want to revoke it immediately after it's used.

Comment: `createObjectURL()` isn't only used for image data, so it can't use image compression.

Comment: @Barmar I did have that thought, but Blobs/Files do have a mime type, so it could perhaps be possible to decompress it at the time of calling `createObjectURL()`. However even if it doesn't decompress the data, it still might not be a thin wrapper, if it made its own copy of the buffer. I'll add that possibility to the question.

Comment: There's no mention of compression in the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-createObjectURL). I would expect the image to be compressed as part of creating the original PNG, JPEG, etc. data, it would be redundant to compress again when converting to a URL.

Comment: The MIME type is used to create the `Content-type` header when retrieving from the URL.

Comment: Oh, I see that `Blob`s are immutable, so `createObjectURL()` wouldn't need to copy for that reason. And I had been wondering if `createObjectURL()` decompressed the data so that the browser could just immediately display it. But thinking more, that does seem unlikely, as all other image display methods would need to handle decompressing the data. So I don't currently have any plausible reason for why `createObjectURL()` *wouldn't* be a thin wrapper, but it would still be good to have it confirmed.

Comment: As I said, there's nothing in the spec that requires it. But there's nothing preventing it as an implementation detail. How would it make a difference?